# How to create 3 dots dropdown button in table row jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I work with a tables, and i need to create 3 dots dropdown list in the table row, i try few librarys and custom dropdown but its working bad.

I want something like this:
[image]

I try to use this library [link](https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Material-Design-Context-Menu-jQuery-3Dot-Context-Menu.html) but for some reason it's not working.

I Create dropdown menu:

HTML:

```
<div class="context-menu-container" id="context-menu-items">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then i add class in to **td**

```
<td class="context-menu" data-container-id="context-menu-items" data-row-id="1"></td>
```

In the table was appered 3 dots, but on clicking is not response

Comment: Without seeing your code we can't tell you why it's not working. do you get any error in the console?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen problem is for some reason librari is not working, and i think or this is some my issues or something else

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen in console i didnt have any errors

Comment: Have you include the Context-menu js and css references in your html ? like https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Material-Design-Context-Menu-jQuery-3Dot-Context-Menu/includes/context-menu.js

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen sure

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the code. Make sure to include all required CSS and JS files.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableContextMenu = new ContextMenu("context-menu-items", menuItemClickListener);
});

function menuItemClickListener(menu_item, parent) {
  alert("Menu Item Clicked: " + menu_item.text() + "\nRecord ID: " + parent.attr("data-row-id"));
}
```

```css
* {
  z-index: 0;
}

input {
  z-index: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.header {
  background: #a30000;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a30000 0%, #d50000 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a30000 0%, #d50000 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a30000 0%, #d50000 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a30000', endColorstr='#d50000', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

#errorToolbox {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #403537;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}

.container-table {
  display: table;
}

.vertical-center-row {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-xs {
  min-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 3000;
}

.navbar-xs .navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 40px;
  z-index: 3000;
}

.navbar-xs .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 37px;
  z-index: 3000;
}


/*
 * Override the bootstrap modal class z-index to ensure it is always above the nav
 * usually only has a problem with the second nav (not the main website nav)
 */

.modal {
  z-index: 5000 !important;
}

#topBar {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 850px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.linkButton {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #E0DFE5;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.linkButton img {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: central;
}

.commentContainer {
  background-color: #E5E1E1;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.rowItem {
  border-bottom: solid thin #7E7C7F !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.bitsTag {
  font-size: x-small;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #A40000;
  color: white;
  border: solid thin black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 115px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  bottom: 0;
}

.appContainer {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border: solid thin #858585;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.appContainer:hover {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.appContainer .title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.appContainer .appID {
  text-align: center;
}

.appIDContainer {
  width: 180px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.data-container {
  background-color: #323436;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.data-container>p.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.data-container-table {
  color: black !important;
}

.data-container-table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
}

.data-container-table>tbody>tr:not(:first-child):hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}

.context-menu:after {
  content: '\2807';
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  pointer-events: all;
}

td.context-menu:after {
  float: right;
}

p.contextMenu:after>span {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

h1.context-menu:after,
h2.context-menu:after,
h3.context-menu:after,
h4.context-menu:after,
h5.context-menu:after {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.context-menu-container {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  border: solid thin black;
  padding: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
  min-width: 90px;
}

.context-menu-container>ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.context-menu-container>ul>li {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.context-menu-container>ul>li:hover {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Material-Design-Context-Menu-jQuery-3Dot-Context-Menu/includes/context-menu.js"></script>
<div class="context-menu-container" id="context-menu-items">
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td class="context-menu" data-container-id="context-menu-items" data-row-id="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4 </td>
    <td class="context-menu" data-container-id="context-menu-items" data-row-id="2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bare-bones example of how something like this can be done.

```js
document.querySelector('table').onclick = ({
  target
}) => {
  if (!target.classList.contains('more')) return
  document.querySelectorAll('.dropout.active').forEach(
    (d) => d !== target.parentElement && d.classList.remove('active')
  )
  target.parentElement.classList.toggle('active')
}
```

```css
.more {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}

.more span {
  display: block;
  width: .25rem;
  height: .25rem;
  background: #363636;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.more span:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: .125rem;
}

.dropout {
  z-index: 9001;
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.dropout ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.1rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.12s ease;
}

.dropout.active ul {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropout">
        <button class="more">
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
        </button>
        <ul>
          <li>
            option 1
          </li>
          <li>
            option 2
          </li>
          <li>
            option 3
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropout">
        <button class="more">
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
        </button>
        <ul>
          <li>
            option 1
          </li>
          <li>
            option 2
          </li>
          <li>
            option 3
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>
      <div class="dropout">
        <button class="more">
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
        </button>
        <ul>
          <li>
            option 1
          </li>
          <li>
            option 2
          </li>
          <li>
            option 3
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dropdown is not visible in table row

Comment: are you sure? look again. I just put it in a table and it works.

Comment: i just add your code to my table, for one sec dropdown is visible, and immediately hide